# How to record page views on a website when using Varnish

Tags: php, mysql, varnish, pageviews

I am developing a news website which is going to have a lot of hits (hopefully).
And we are building it around PHP Laravel Mysql and Varnish.

My question is how can we know how many views a news page had?
Do we do a google api request from time to time?
Or do we increment a counter in db trough Varnish?

Anyone had this issue before?
We dont want to reinvent anything which is already standard..

One idea I had is to make an AJAX POST record on page load and make it randomly once in 100 requests lets say but is very strange. 
There must be better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I think this question might be primarily opinion-based which is against Stackoverflow rules.

If I were you I'll just use Google Analytics, it'll save you time, headaches and give you a lot of additional features that could be useful for you.

But nether less if you want to do it without using an external public service just for the sake of learning something new, you could enable access logs in your varnish, send them to ElasticSearch and with Kibana you can create dashboards giving you that kind of information. This is what is called an ELK stack.

You can find more information about that here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/getting-started-with-elk

Comment: Thanks Garcia. But how do I implement that? I do requests from time to time to google with a cron - lets say for the news on the first page I do requests once in 2 minutes? And then when page loads I make a new ajax request to load them into page? Something like this isnt it? The issue I might run into is that I will have to make too many requests and work on the server which could be even bigger than making myself the saving trough Varnish?

Comment: Yes, but Google Analytics will show you unique visits, whereas varnish just page hits and you'll have to put the logic to transform those into unique visits (assuming that's what you want).

Answer (score 0):

**You should use a frontend Analytics solution** (e.g. Google Analytics, Mixpanel, Piwik etc...), that's what they are for: they run on the client side (browser), so it doesn't matter whether your pages are cached or not, whether requests actually hit your servers or not etc...: **as long as your clients can load pages in their browser, they will load the analytics code (JavaScript) which will then collect data about page views**.

Advantages over backend analytics:

- No infrastructure required
- Plug-and-play (most tools work by just adding a few line of JavaScript)
- Not bloating your code/SLowing down your app with analytics API calls

Comment: hi Max - my problem is how do I know page views for each news page - in order to show the number on the page - this article was read 1000 times.

Comment: Sorry but you're mixing up so many concepts ("new page", "page view" , "article", "read") that I'm confused.